# Concatenation in shell script and use of 'basename'

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to read all file names form a particular directory and then create new files with those names by appending some string to them in another directory.

e.g > 'A', 'B', 'C' are in 'logs' directory
then script should create 'A_tmp', 'B_tmp', 'C_tmp' in 'tmp' directory

what i am using is -

```
tempDir=./tmp/
logDir=./logs/

for file in $( find `echo $logDir` -type f )
 do
      name=eval basename $file
      echo $name
      name=$(echo $name | sed 's/.$//')
      echo $tempDir
      opFile=$tempDir$name
      echo $opFile
 done
```

But what I understood is, $file is containing '\n' as last character and I am unable to concatenate the string.

right now I am not creating files, just printing all the names.

So, how I can remove the '\n' from the file name, and is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Analysis

There are multiple issues to address in your script.  Let's take it step by step:

```
tempDir=./tmp/
logDir=./logs/

for file in $( find `echo $logDir` -type f )
```

This scheme assumes no spaces in the file names (which is not an unusual restriction; avoiding problems with spaces in names is relatively tricky).  Also, there's no need for the `echo`; just write:

```
for file in $(find "$logDir" -type f)
```

Continuing:

```
do
    name=eval basename $file
```

This runs the `basename` command with the environment variable `name` set to the value `eval` and the argument `$file`.  What you need here is:

```
    name=$(basename "$file")
```

where the double quotes aren't strictly necessary because the name can't contain spaces (but it's not a bad habit to get into to quote all file names because sometimes the names do contain spaces).

```
    echo $name
```

This would echo a blank line because name was not set.

```
    name=$(echo $name | sed 's/.$//')
```

If name was set, this would chop off the last character, but if the name was `A`, you'd have nothing left.

```
    echo $tempDir
    opFile=$tempDir$name
    echo $opFile
done
```

Give or take double quotes and the fact that you've not added the `_tmp` suffix to `opFile`, there's nothing wrong with the rest.

#### Synthesis

Putting the changes together, you end up with:

```
tempDir=./tmp/
logDir=./logs/

for file in $(find "$logDir" -type f)
do
    name=$(basename "$file")
    echo "$name"                    # Debug only
    echo "$tempDir"                 # Debug only
    opFile="$tempDir${name}_tmp"
    echo "$opFile"
done
```

That shows all the intermediate results.  You could perfectly well compress that down to:

```
tempDir=./tmp/
logDir=./logs/

for file in $(find "$logDir" -type f)
do
    opFile="$tempDir"$(basename "$file")"_tmp"
    echo "$opFile"
done
```

Or, using a simpler combination of double quotes because the names contain no spaces:

```
tempDir=./tmp/
logDir=./logs/

for file in $(find "$logDir" -type f)
do
    opFile="$tempDir$(basename $file)_tmp"
    echo "$opFile"
done
```

The echo is there as a surrogate for the copy or move operation you plan to execute, of course.

EDIT: ...and to remove restrictions on file names containing spaces and globbing characters, do it as:

```
tempDir=./tmp/
logDir=./logs/

find "$logDir" -type f |
while IFS= read -r file
do
    opFile="${tempDir}${file##*/}_tmp"
    echo "$opFile"
done
```

It will still fail for file names containing newlines. If you want to handle that then investigate a solution using `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` or `find ... -exec`.

Comment: I cant even comment here, Thanx a ton for this description !
Helped a lot ! thank you for your precious time.

Comment: some more help req -
when i execute 

`sed 's/.*-> \([^(]*\).*\( .*\):\([0-9]*$\)/function \1\ncalled from \2\nat line number \3\n/' inputFileName > outputFileName`

on command line, it executes fine but when i try same thing from shell script it throws an error - `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

can u please suggest anything here ?

Comment: Got the answer, i was using EVAL in shell script for execution sed commnad, now removed that, its working now.

I will check exact use of eval in script now.

Comment: I have a few scripts  that use `eval` (26 that I've written and am still using out of hundreds — 322 shell scripts in my `bin` directory); it is a last resort and dangerous weapon. You should assume that `eval` is the wrong answer until you are sure you know why it's the correct answer, and are aware of the risks entailed in using it. If the users supply the input, the risk is non-negligible. And working out how the `eval` of a `sed` script replete with regular expression metacharacters will work is the sort of thing sadistic teachers set for finals exams; not the sort of thing you do for fun.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler++ `eval` should be pronouced "evil".

Comment: Do not do `for file in $(find...)` or `for file in $(ls...)` as that very unnecessarily excludes file names containing spaces. Also, the way you're using `basename $file` will fail in interesting ways for file names containing globbing characters! I updated the answer to address those issues.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
#!/bin/sh

tmpDir=./tmp/
logDir=./logs/

# list all files in log directory, pipe into a loop that reads each path line
# by line..
# Also note that there is no newline in this case since it is swallowed by 'read'.
find $logDir -type f | while read path; do
    # get the basename of the path
    name=`basename $path`
    # copy the found file to the temporary directory.
    dest="$tmpDir/${name}_tmp"
    echo $dest
done
```

Shell scripts have the ability to concatenate strings easily in statements, as demonstrated with **$tmpDir/${name}_tmp**, there is no need for replacing the output since read swallows any newlines.

**find ... while read** is a very useful construct when you want to read multiple lines of anything, it even works for files.

```
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < filename.txt
```

Edit: clarified

Comment: Yeah, thanx for the good explanation in the answer, will try it without sed now !

Comment: One thing, as I am using "cp" commnad, it will copy those files with sifferent name, but I dnt want to perform this creation of files, I am interested in names_tmp only, so for that purpose I have to use "tr" !.. right ?

Comment: Basically just echo instead of cp then, there is no newline in this case since 'read' swallows it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
tempDir=./tmp/
logDir=./logs/

for file in $( find `echo $logDir` -type f )
  do
    name=`eval basename $file|tr -d "\n"`_tmp
    echo $name
  done
```

Comment: You don't need the `eval` or the `tr`; you could use: `name="$tempDir$(basename $file)_tmp"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
name=eval basename $file
```

to

```
name=`eval basename $file`
```

then afterwads name contains what you want.

Comment: I tried this, but was unable to get new file name as required.